# basis of a kernel if is it a Empty set

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, linear-transformations

I found a strange question

**give me the basis of kernel?**

i go to find the set of kernel by slove the eqation f(u) = O

i do a matrix  of the systhem linear (f(u)=0) that i found but

the matrix is note  invertible that mean the

set of solution is empty set

i mean that **kernel is a Empty set**

the problem how i find **basis of a Empty set ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel of a linear transformation is **never** empty, since for any vector spaces $V$ and $W$, and any linear transformation $f:V\to W$, it must be true that
$$f(0_V)=0_W$$
and therefore $0_V\in\ker(f)$. However, it is true that
$$f\text{ is injective}\iff \ker(f)=\{0_V\}$$
in which case you have the question of how to find a basis of the subspace $\{0_V\}$ of $V$ (again, this is **not** empty). But even though the subspace $\{0_V\}$ is not empty, the empty set $\varnothing$ is a basis of that subspace.

Note that, in particular, it is **wrong** to say that $\{0_V\}$ is a basis of $\{0_V\}$, since for example, 
$$17\cdot 0_V = 0_V$$
shows how a nontrivial linear combination of the set $\{0_V\}$ can produce the zero vector.

Any linear combination of the vectors in the set $\varnothing$ (of course, there actually **aren't** any vectors in $\varnothing$) that produces the zero vector must be a trivial linear combination (after all, which of the coefficients is a non-zero scalar?)

Comment: ya the kernel never empty thx u that mean i have problem in calculation

Comment: but how u find the basis  of set has just the zero vector

Comment: The empty set $\varnothing$ is a basis of $\{0_V\}$ - I've added more to my answer.

Comment: ok thanks u bro